# Searchview appear on each row of listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

the searchview appears on each listview row: Check the scrrenshot attached.

How can i make it apppear only once, at the top.

```
xml:
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home"
    android:padding="30dp"
   >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ED0316"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
        android:textColor="#fafafa"
        android:id="@+id/txt" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search here..."
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:focusedByDefault="t`enter code here`rue"
        android:transitionName="Search_box"
        android:id="@+id/search_view">

    </SearchView>
</FrameLayout>
```

[enter image description here][1]

public class contractorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
SearchView searchView;
public contractorAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList ArrayList) {
super(context, R.layout.fragment_home, ArrayList);

```
}
public static class ViewHolder {
    SearchView searchView;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    searchView.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); // set it visible if it is at position 0. Else set it invisible
    return convertView;
}
```

}
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAsZq.png

Comment: can you post the entire adapter code

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. You can just pass the `position` of the `ViewHolder` to the `ViewHolder` class. If the `position == 0`, set the view visible. Else. set it invisible. It can also be done easily like this:

```
search_view.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

A sample adapter code could be like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        SearchView searchView;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        searchView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); // set it visible if it is at position 0. Else set it invisible
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: do provide the code thanks.

Comment: the searchview is still appearing on each line of the list view!  Is there any other reason for that?

Comment: `searchView.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);` this is the main code. Does this not work?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: ok. try this -> `searchView.setVisibility(position == 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);`

Comment: same bro..do u think its the xml?..the searchview is appearing >1500..since each line is populated by my db

Comment: please add the entire adapter code to your question. That will help us to help you

Comment: do check it now

Answer (score 0):

If You Use Recycler view for Showing list then you remove search view from the recycler item and put search view in the main activity.

And If You Not Use Recycler View Then Try Below Code

```
  if (position == 0){
        searchView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        searchView.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```